# The condtion for Augmented Langrangian Multiplier

Tags: constrained-optimization, constraints, lagrange-multiplier

I am currently learning the usage of Augmented Lagrangian Multiplier to achieve my equality constraint. I have learnt from the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_Lagrangian_method that I have two multipliers, $\mu$ and $\lambda$.

According to wikipedia, it shows me how I can update my $\lambda$ with any value of $\mu$. However, this gets my curiosity. Since it did not mention the condition for setting initial $\lambda$ and $\mu$, can both of them be negative value initially, and also during the iterations?

Comment: The penalty parameter ($\mu$ in your notation) should start at a positive value.  Various schemes are used to increase the penalty parameter in a dynamic fashion.  From a theoretical point of view (not useful in practice), any sufficiently large value of the penalty parameter will do.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! In that case, how about the $\lambda$, is it necessary to be positive value too?

Comment: For equality constraints, $c_{i}(x)=0$, the Lagrange multiplier $\lambda_{i}$ can be positive or negative or even 0.